# Which volatility to use?

Tags: options, volatility, greeks

For calculating the greeks
http://www.vollib.org/html/apidoc/vollib.black.greeks.html
Should I use historical volatility or implied volatility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know what Greeks the market assigns to an option, i.e. the market implied Greeks, then you would use the implied volatility. And that is what traders like to look at.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using greeks for your past trading session's analysis , you should use historical Vol

If you intend to make trading decisions in future and want to have a future outlook of greeks, you should use implied Vol.